# How to create type which can be returned through another type implicitly in Swift?

Tags: swift, init

In C++ we can model a type like below,

```cpp
struct Q{};
struct P{
     P(Q q){}
};
P fun(){return Q();} // implicitly call P(Q()) as return result
```

How to do that in Swift?

```swift
struct Q {}

struct P {
     init(_ q: Q){}
}
var p : P {Q()} // Cannot convert return expression of type 'Q' to return type 'P'

var p : P {P(Q())} // OK!
```

Comment: Could you explain in words rather than c++ code what it is you want to achieve?

Comment: I checked out `AnyView` and `AnyHashable` type info which like a wrapper to wrap types conforming to specific protocols (view/hashable) through `init<T: P>(_ value: T){}`; but I want to create a type which can only be created from specific type like `init(_ q: Q)` and return Q() instead of P(Q()) directly in property or function. 

The problem is I can't find any way to achieve that in Swift but it's so easy in C/C++ fashion.

Comment: As a general rule, no, by design. Swift avoids implicit conversions. There are specia lcases, such as the ExpressibleBy...Literal protocols that convert literals to types, but as a rule, Swift conversions are intentionally explicit. It won't even convert Float to Double implicitly. Do you have a deeper problem you're trying to solve that makes this implicitness important?